# React app keeps sending continuous HTTP requests

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page that displays data fetched from a MongoDb through API, in this page, you can modify the data and after that, the page will render again to display the new data. But inspecting the network requests I noticed my react app sends an infinite number of requests, which obviously slows down everything. I read this is caused by this snippet of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [users]);
```

I also read I must empty the dependencies array of the useEffect, but If I do so, the page will not re-render if the data changes (for example after inserting a new record in the db).
This is the function I use to get the data from the db:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/users/");
    if (res.status === 401) {
        console.log(res.json);
    } else {
        setUsers(await res.json());
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Remove users dependency from useEffect. 2. fetchData() - pass this as a call back function , so once the insert into Database is done just call this callback function. So this will eliminate continuous loop call and only fetches the data after the insert

Comment: You don't need to fetch the new record after inserting, since the data you are inserting is available on UI. You can simply show this data directly on UI once the insert API call was successful. Another way is you will get inserted record id back from the API call so you can use that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You created an infinite loop:

`fetchData` calls `setUsers`, which sets `users`. The effect reacts to changes to `users`, and calls `fetchData` again. ♾️

I don't know your exact use case, but one solution would be to only call `fetchData` when an actual user interaction has happend in your app that makes you want to fetch new data.

Comment: How would you only call fetchData once? AFAIK you can only use async functions in the useEffect function?

Comment: You can call `fetchData` in any way you like. For example, you could call it in the `onClick` event handler of a button.

Comment: I have another related problem. How can I call fetchData, which is defined in Users, in User? User is substantially a child of Users, it renders the rows of the table letting the user to modify or remove data from the db. fetchData() causes the refresh of the Users's view because it modifies setUsers (that is passing the new database object). Thanks.